# Haskell parallel program launch arguments

Tags: shell, haskell, concurrency, command-line-arguments

I have programmed a Haskell program which works in a Unix utility manner - you launch the program, it gets the job done, and exits.
I used concurrency in that program, but for it to be really concurrent, one has to compile it respectively, and furthermore, what surprises me, launch compiled program with some additional arguments.
I compiled it with:

`ghc -O2 -threaded --make Main.hs -o Main.parallel`

And it seems to work in parallel when I run it like that:

`./Main.parallel ds_houses/task.txt 8 500000 1:+1 +RTS -N8
./Main.parallel ds_houses/task.txt 8 500000 +RTS -N8
./Main.parallel ds_houses/task.txt 8 +RTS -N8
./Main.parallel ds_houses/task.txt +RTS -N8`

I use arguments `8`, `500000` and `1:+1` because I saw them [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Concurrency_demos/Zeta), in the shell script.

I understand the first argument as cores of CPU, but what are others? It doesn't seem that those arguments are used by `/usr/bin/time` program, because if you add `%C` to its format, these arguments are shown as arguments for benchmarked program.

Can someone explain or point me to what these arguments do?
Is my assumption true, that one's Haskell compiled program accepts not only arguments expected by programmer, but also other arguments that are forwarded to Haskell runtime?

Comment: Arguments before `+RTS` mean whatever you ask your program to do with them. If you don't have `getArgs` in your program, they will all just be ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguments between `+RTS ... -RTS` are intercepted by the runtime and not passed to your program (`-RTS` is optional if the arguments are at the end of the call). Everything else will be consumed by your program.

So the answer to your question is in the program's code - specifically the usage message reads: `usage: zeta <nthreads> <boundary> <s>`, which makes more sense if you compile with `ghc -O2 -threaded --make Main.hs -o zeta`. Have a look at the functions to see how these are being used.

Comment: Thanks, well explained, now it's much more clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer addresses you question as asked, but I want to address this off-hand comment:

> for it to be really concurrent, one has to... launch compiled program with some additional arguments.

(I understood this as a complaint which you would like to fix.) One can also design the program to use additional OS threads even without having the RTS options using the [`Control.Concurrent`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html) API. In particular, `getNumCapabilities` and `setNumCapabilities` read and write the number of OS threads dedicated to evaluating Haskell code. You may also like `rtsSupportsBoundThreads` to check whether the program was compiled with the right threading flags and [`getNumProcessors`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/GHC-Conc.html#v:getNumProcessors) to check how many CPUs are available to run threads on.